# Best practice to store several static data in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa

I need to store pre-configured values that later will be used for selections that the user may choose from a table in iOS app, probably around 5-10 of choices. 
What is the best way to store these kind of data in terms of performance and efficiency?
I might think of several methods like:

- hard-coded right in the rendering method
- array
- plist file
- core data

Thanks

Comment: All your examples looks well-suited for PRE-configured values in program, not for something user input.

Comment: @kirilloid sorry if it was unclear at first, yes actually i am asking for storing pre-configured values that the user can choose from, nothing to do with user input

Comment: Core data is overkill. Either hardcode it into the rendering method or, if you think the code may be useful in other places, use a plist file containing an array or dictionary. Load the plist file once and keep the data in memory if you are worried about efficiency.

Comment: Hard-coded values ain't good anyway. `plist` looks better than any other option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is really just about 5 to 10 data items then you may store them in an NSDictionary or Array and save that in an plist file and read from it. You can use the `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` method or `arrayWithContentsOfFile` respectively to read from the plist and use `writeToFile` for writing.

For lager amount of data you can look into core data.

Answer (score 4):

Static data should be stored in static variables of the appropriate class which will load the values.

Whether you load the dictionary from a file or not here is how to load the dictionary or array statically so its only ever done once in your application.

```
//.h
@interface MyApp

+(void) initialize; //will only be called once when the class is loaded

//.m

static NSArray *myListOfStuff;

@implementation MyApp

+(void) initialize {
    //...either load your values from a file or hard code the values here
    //init and assign values to myListOfStuff
}

//a statis getter for the list
+(NSArray *) listOfStuff {
    return myListOfStuff;
}


//Client Code to get the list in your app
NSArray *myList = [MyApp listOfStuff];

//This memory will not be released for the life of the application.
//it will be loaded once and only once - its efficient
```

Google persisting a dictionary or array to a plist if persistence is what you are after
what Im showing you is how to structure loading static data in your object model efficiently
regardless of the persistence approach